# Writing loop of uncertain size of array

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

Below code is working fine.

```
private int[] list = new int[]{ 3, 5, 10};
private int[] temp = new int[list.length];

public void Generate()
{
    for (int a=0;a<list[0];a++)
    {
        temp[0] = a;
        for (int b=0;b<list[1];b++)
        {
            temp[1] = b;
            for (int c=0;c<list[2];c++)
            {
                temp[2] = c;
                int[] asd = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I change list array length I have to add a for loop inside. How can I write one method for any size of list array? For example:

```
private int[] list = new int[]{ 2, 5, 12,18};
```

the code doesn't work!

Comment: What language is this? Java? C#?

Comment: This is java code

Comment: I would recommend using recursion to "generate" your for loops. ie. The for loop is in a helper recursive function that calls itself on increasing index values. Then, when you hit the base case, you just assign/print/return/mutate/&c the result and pop back up. Using recursion and iteration together is probably the easiest to implement instead of converting everything into a solely iterative function (though any recursive function can be reimplemented as an iterative one...).

Comment: I research that. Can you write an example?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what your function is supposed to result in, but if you want the equivalent to your code in a single function, then it would look like this (assuming C# as the language):

```
private int[] list = new int {3, 5, 10};

public void Generate()
{
    List<string> toPrint = new List<string>();
    string num_string = string.Empty;    
    string base_string = string.Empty;
    for(int i=list.length; i>-1; i--)
    {
        num_string = num_string + list[i].ToString();
        base_string = base_string +'0';
    }
    lastnumber = Int16.parse(num_string[list.length - 1]);
    int string_length = base_string.length;
    bool running = true;
    while(running)
    {   
        bool finished = true;
        for(int incre=0; incre < lastnumber; incre ++)
        {
            string temp = base_string;
            temp[string_length-1] = (char)incre;
            toPrint.add(temp);
        }
        for(int i = 2; i <= base_string.length; i++ )
        {
            int currentnumber = Int16.Parse(base_string[base_string.length - i]);
            int number_limit = Int16.Parse(num_string[base_string.length -i]));
            if(currentnumber < number_limit)
            {
                currentnumber = currentnumber +1;
                base_string[base_string.length - i] = (char)currentnumber
                finished = false;
                break;
            }

            if(finished)
            {
                base_string[base_string.length - i] = 0
            }
        }

        if(finished)
        {
            running = false;
        }

    }
    string [] asd = toPrint.ToArray()
}
```

Is this what you are looking for? If not, could you provide more details so I can have better context?

Comment: My code prints [0,0,0] [0,0,1][0,0,2]...[0,0,10][0,1,0] [0,1,0] in the end finishes [3,5,10]

Comment: I see. I edited the code based on your above comment

Comment: Thank you for your effort.I cant run this code yet because base_string[base_string.length - i] = currentnumber here base_string last char cannot cast to integer. Should i replace?

Comment: Apologies on my part. I added a cast on that line so it should work. What language are you using?

Comment: If this works for you, can you select it as the answer. Thanks.